# How can i make mosquitto run over ssl?

Tags: ssl, mosquitto

I'm trying to run mosquitto on port 8883 over ssl. My config file is given below

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 8083
protocol websockets

listener 8883
protocol websockets
require_certificate true
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/client.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/client.crt

user root
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto.log
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
log_type all
```

I have added client.key and client.crt file but can't find which file to add on ca.crt

Can anyone tell me where to find ca.crt file ?

I'm using centos7 with whm panel
Used Let's encrypt certificates.

Running mosquitto over ssl

Answer (score 0):

There is no need fo require_certificate true

When using certificate based encryption there are three options that affect authentication. The first is require_certificate, which may be set to true or false. If false, the SSL/TLS component of the client will verify the server but there is no requirement for the client to provide anything for the server